# Notification working on Emulator but not on my device

Tags: android, notifications, deprecated

Im developing an app that runs on API 7 and above so I have to used `NotificationCompat.Builder` instead of Notification because it deprecated in higher version. This works fine on emulator, but when tested on my device there was no `notification`. Please can somebody help me.
NB: Is it not possible to use just an API for API 7 to 14. I will like to know because my device uses API 7

Answer (score 2):

try this function - it works on android 2 up to 4 :

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;



    public static void pushNotification(final Context context,
            int icon, String name, String descr, Intent activityIntent) {
        NotificationManager notifyMgr = 
                (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService( 
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0, activityIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
            notification = getNotification8(context, 
                    icon, name, descr, when, pIntent);
        else notification = getNotification11(context, 
                icon, name, descr, when, pIntent);
        notifyMgr.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Notification getNotification8(Context context,
            int icon, String name, String descr, 
            long when, PendingIntent pIntent) {
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, name, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, name, descr, pIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        return notification;
    }   
    @TargetApi(11)
    private static Notification getNotification11(Context context,
            int icon, String name, String descr, 
            long when, PendingIntent pInten) {
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setTicker(name)
            .setContentTitle(name)
            .setContentText(descr)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentIntent(pInten)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setWhen(when)
            .getNotification();     
        return notification;
    }
```